# Alternating functional Series Convergence SOS....

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following series converge?
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^k \sqrt{k}}{k!}$

what is the radius of convergence?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{k}<k.$ Then 
$\left| \frac{(-1)^k x^k \sqrt{k}}{k!} \right|<\frac{|x|^k k}{k!}=\frac{|x|^k}{(k-1)!}.$
For the series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty {\frac{|x|^k}{(k-1)!}}$ the radius of convergence $R=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{k!}{(k-1)!}=\ldots$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, according to the existence of the $(-1)^k$ can we still claim that it is possible to use the fact that $\sqrt{k}<k$?

Comment: You will prove *absolute* convergence* for all $x$, which implies convergence.

Comment: Thank you Andre, However we are aiming at showing that this series converges to a limmited value for all $x$. Is it possible?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Strochyk... We may have not asked the right question. Is it possible to show that $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^k \sqrt{k}}{k!}$ converges even when $x\rightarrow \infty$ ?

Please note that $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^k }{k!} \rightarrow e^{-x}$ and converges for all values of $x$.

Comment: We can state that power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^k \sqrt{k}}{k!}$  with infinite radius of convergence  converges uniformly on every compact $K\subset\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. could you please explain more?:)

Comment: It's a standard fact of the theory of  power series:  power series converges absolutely inside the interval (or disk) of convergence and converges uniformly on every compact subset of that interval.

Comment: Thank you. But can we claim that $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^k \sqrt{k}}{k!}$ is bounded for all values of $x$? i.e $\forall x: f(x)< \infty$

Comment: As noted by Robert Israel, the series doesn't converge uniformly on whole $\mathbb{R}$ and is not uniformly bounded: $(\nexists M>0):\;\;(\forall{x}\in\mathbb{R}) \ \ \  \ |f(x)|< M.$

Comment: Is there a proof for that ?

Comment: One could (should?) compute directly the radius of convergence of the original series using the formula recalled at the end for the modified series.

Comment: For $x<0$ denoting $t=-x$ we have that partial sums $f_N(-t) = \sum_{k=0}^N \frac{t^k \sqrt{k}}{k!}>\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{t^k }{k!}\to e^t$ as $N\to\infty,$ therefore,  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k \sqrt{k}}{k!}$ is unbounded as $t\to\infty.$

Comment: Can we claim that it converges for posetive values of $x$?

Comment: It converges for every fixed value of $x.$

Comment: Thank you Mr. Strochyk, I mean that can we say that it converges to a bounded function for posetive values of x? In other words can we sya that $f(x)$ is bounded for posetive values of $x$?